# jquery easing breaks jquery on wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, easing

Im getting an error when i add the jquery easing 1.3 plugin to my page, i havent even used custom easing yet but just loading it stops animated elements working. Im not a jquery expert so i dont really know how to debug it but im fairly sure that there is a conflict, heres the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

The error is triggered when you roll over the animated elements, heres the page im working on:

http://www.pegbarandgrill.com/blog/

if you roll over the links & directory you should see an animated menu open but this is when you will get the error. I sourced jquery and easing with the following lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/pegbarAndGrill_01/script/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/pegbarAndGrill_01/script/easing.js"></script>
```

Also if i remove the wp_head() and wp_footer() functions the conflict goes away. Any idea what the problem might be?

Many thanks

Comment: Sometimes replacing `$` with `jQuery` fixes the problem in WordPress. Try that.

Comment: It's an error on the plugin part, it may simply be incompatible with jQuery 1.7 or even previous.

Comment: You are loading another version of jQuery (1.6.x) after you already loaded the easing, I guess getting rid of that might help you (see line 25 of your source code)

Comment: hmmm, interesting, wordpress loads its own jquery, does anyone know how to upgrade it? also if i load easing before jquery will i get errors?

Comment: You should basically load the scripts in the following order: 1. jQuery, 2. jQuery plugins (easing in your case), 3. actual script content, everything else tends to get messy, so yes you'll be in trouble if you load the easing before the jQuery (it builds on jQuery...)

Comment: thanks everyone, ive managed to fix all the problems by re ordering things but i can help get the nagging feeling that im doing this the wrong way, does anyone know if there is a 'correct' way to include your own scrupts etc rather than adding your own link?

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap contents of easing.js file with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
});
```

It saved my time before!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message.  I had jQuery, jQuery UI, the easing plugin, and a call to `jQuery.noConflict()` in the wrong order.

I had been using `jQuery.noConflict()` to get around some other problem from a long time ago, but I no longer needed that so I removed it.

I then put the `<script>` elements in this order:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

This fixed the problem.